# Drupal commerce auto login during checkout

Tags: commerce

I have e-commerce site, during checkout process it automatically create account for anonymous user. I have added following two rules to achieve this ***Assign an anonymous order to a pre-existing user*** and ***Create a new account for an anonymous order***. What I want is instead of creating account i want the user to automatically login during checkout

I have tried [Commerce Checkout Complete Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_complete_registration), but I am facing some error, when user enter the email address and moves to next page
the site goes maintenance mode. When I checked the dblog it throws the exception

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unable to set the data property uid as the parent data structure is not set. in EntityStructureWrapper->setProperty() (line 473 of /home/knackforge/Public/dropts/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

When i refresh the page user is automatically logged in.
 Is there any way resolve this error. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to use [commerce_checkout_redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect)

Comment: @SwarnenduDutta I have used https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_complete_registration  module, but getting exception mentioned above

Comment: I tried the module and it works fine for me..Did you deactivate the previous  rules and try ??

Comment: I have disabled billing information from checkout form. Is this the reason for this error

Comment: I dont think so..